# can dronekit be use with cx-10wd-tx mini

Tags: python-2.7, dronekit

I am a programmer and just started getting into drones. I stumbled across dronekit and got to thinking about controlling the drone with code. so i am kind of new to this and really need some help.

i want to control a mini drone with code.  i want to use python and drone kit to do this.

I have tried to connect to the mini i have but i am getting an error in the code saying it times out trying to connect.

i have a cx-10wd-tx drone, can dronkit be used to control this drone, if not is there a mini that can be used?

Comment: You would need a drone running [ArduPilot](http://ardupilot.org) (or other mavlink-compatible flight controller).  I suspect the cheapest option may be the recently released [SkyViper](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/skyrocket.html).

Comment: how do i know if my drone is running arduPilot